# Use an audio element's play method as the callback to setTimeout, why not?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, html5-audio

I have a reference to an `audio` tag whose `play` method I can call like so:

```
voice["blessed be"].play()
```

if I try to call it like:

```
setTimeout(voice["blessed be"].play, 1000)
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

I'm not necessarily going to use `setTimeout` in the final implementation; but, why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how `setTimeout` calls its callbacks.  It calls the callback functions with the context set to `window`.

So, it's calling `voice["blessed be"].play.call(window)`.  <strike>This is like calling `window.play`, which doesn't work.</strike>  You're taking the play function of an audo element, and forcing it to be ran on the `window` object.  `window` isn't an audo element, so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something along the lines of

```
var sound = voice[ 'blessed be' ];
setTimeout( sound.play.bind( sound ), 1000 );
```